# how to avoid "list index out of range" in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so I'm trying to write a code that searches through a string looking for two separate strings (with no intersection): 'AB' and 'BA'

finding them both: print('YES')

else: print('NO')

---

when I test 'ABAB' which should end up with a 'NO', this error comes up:

**list index out of range**:
for line 6

what do you think?

```
phrase = input()
phrase_list = []
if phrase.find('AB') != -1:
    phrase = phrase.replace('AB', ' ', 1)
    phrase_list = phrase.split()
    if phrase_list[0].find('BA') != -1 or phrase_list[1].find('BA') != -1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')                
else:
     print('NO')
```

Comment: If you are okay with finding `'BA'` in both of two parts after split, so why splitting at all?

Comment: What is the point of the `.split()` call here?

Comment: I don't understand why you split?

Comment: I used replace and split so that It can search each part separately (as list Items). for example if the phrase is 'BABA', there are two 'AB's and one 'BA' but they are not separated (they have Intersections). The answer for this phrase should be 'NO' but not using split and replace will end up to BABA --> BA (finding AB at first and then BA) and printing a 'YES'

Comment: Check my answer below I understand now why you were splitting and I utilised the same technique

Comment: What output do you expect from 'ABAAB'?  If you replace the first 'AB' the only 'BA' will be destroyed. But if you replace the last 'AB' instead then you will find 'BA' too.

Comment: Use `phrase = phrase.replace('AB', '* ', 1)` if it's okay to use an additional `*` character. This modification guarantees that the splitting operation yields a list with 2 items, thus avoiding the index error.

Comment: @Jolbas you are absolutely right, thanks.
any ideas?

Comment: @ack, good idea but reading jolbas comment just found out it still would have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace with a character you are sure not to be in any of the search strings then you are probably fine by just removing the split. If you want 'ABAAB' to return 'YES'. Then you can add a second pass that is looking for the second string first.

```
phrase = input()
if phrase.find('AB') >= 0 and phrase.replace('AB', ' ', 1).find('BA') >= 0:
    print('YES')
elif phrase.find('BA') >= 0 and phrase.replace('BA', ' ', 1).find('AB') >= 0:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: That is clean and smart. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to consult [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  You also need to try incremental programming: you've coded past errors to make more errors -- learn to make only one at a time.  :-)

A simple bit of tracing shows the problem:

```
phrase = "ABAB"
phrase_list = []
if phrase.find('AB') != -1:
    print("\nTRACE 1", phrase)
    phrase = phrase.replace('AB', ' ', 1)
    phrase_list = phrase.split()
    print("TRACE 2", phrase_list)
    if phrase_list[0].find('BA') != -1 or phrase_list[1].find('BA') != -1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')                
else:
     print('NO')
```

Output:

```
TRACE 1 ABAB
TRACE 2 ['AB']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\so.py", line 8, in <module>
    if phrase_list[0].find('BA') != -1 or phrase_list[1].find('BA') != -1:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You remove two characters from the input, split it into a list of a single string, but somehow expect the list to have two strings for you to index.  This causes the error.

I can't "fix" your logic, because you haven't explained how you expect this to work, and the flow is not apparent from your code.

Comment: thanks! yes, now I understand. Don't know how that slipped my mind because I thought about it. thanks again